# How to mention the author of the message in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js, bots

I can't seem to find any exact guide on how to author-mention on Discord.js. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way to mentions a user

```js
// With ID
message.channel.send(`mention with id <@${message.author.id}>`);
// With user object
message.channel.send(`mention with user ${message.member.user}`);
//With builtin reply
message.reply(`mention with reply`);
```

Comment: Why are you using `message.member.user` instead of `message.author`?

Comment: It is short way to get user id from `.author`

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are really many ways but: `<@${message.author.id}>` would be a simple answer.